# Setup Django2, python3 at apache wiith virtualenv and WSGI

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I setup my site.conf in with theses configs:

WSGIDaemonProcess linkb1 python-path=/home/test/public/linkb1/public_html:/home/test/vlinkbox/lib/python3.6/site-packages

But when i run django i see this error:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

At my terminal python -V is 3.6.3. I use ubuntu 14.04

How solved this?

Comment: Despite your claim of Python 3.6, it very much sounds like the Django 2.0 process is executed with Python 2 (there was no `lru_cache` in the `functools` module in Python 2).

Comment: really, but i don't know why this happens python is set to python 3.6.